# Time is in absolute Motion Or Not?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time, coordinate-systems

I just want to know If Time is actually moving forward in one direction or is there anything in the universe for which the time is actually at rest despite the fact that it's actually moving forward for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Particles that travel at light speed such as photons experience no time passage (their proper time is stationary).  Other bodies that experience strong gravitational fields such as those close to black holes will appear to us to have their clocks stopped but they themselves will see time progressing normally.  The whole question of the passage of time and direction of the arrow of time is a very deep and interesting one.  For instance, positrons can be thought of as electrons moving backwards in time.  For more info look up “arrow of time” and “Feynman diagrams”.

Comment: It's because there's a form of double-entry accounting going on. A positron moving in one direction, is functionally equivalent to an electron moving in the opposite direction, if what you're measuring is the balance of charges. This implies going backwards in time or pulling an electron from the future, if you define time in a muddled fashion to begin with.  I believe Feynman and Wheeler knocked together the so-called transactional interpretation of QM based on this.